# IE animation top not working

Tags: internet-explorer, animation

i have a responsive rectagnle div , that has a div inside of it with initail properties of
position, absolute and top 0f 100%,

when hover i want the inner div to change from top 100% to top 0px, and im doing it with a transition 
( note the `tranistion: top 2s`)

for some reason this code is working great on chrome, but for IE the transition in not happening well, the div gets top of 0px right away and there is no animation effect.

does IE have some problem animating top position to 0?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 pull-right" data-projects-dir53="1" style="display: block;">            
            <div class="projectBox" style="background-image:url('/Warehouse/content/pics/pic_250_A.jpg');">
                <div data-toggle="ajaxModal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="LoadProjectData(250);">
                    <div class="s-vert-parent text-center">
                        <div class="child-vert box-text-contain">
                            <h3>שתי דקות</h3>
                            <p class="hidden-xs"></p>
                            <a class="open-plus-icon" data-toggle="ajaxModal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="LoadProjectData(250);"><img alt="פלוס" src="../../../000Frames/site/images/plus_icon.png"></a>
                        </div>   
                    </div>         
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css code :

```
.projectBox > div {
display:block; 
position:absolute;
top:100%; 
right:0px;
left:0px;
padding-bottom:67%; 
-webkit-transition: top 1s; 
transition: top 1s; 
color:White; 
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
background-color:RGBA(239,65,61,0.9); 
}
.projectBox:hover > div , .projectBox:focus > div { top:0px; right:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; }
```

Comment: Please remove all `<%` like markup and provide just the output HTML instead.

Comment: I tried to copy/paste you code in http://jsfiddle.net/ but it even didn't show. Looks like there are some broken HTML.